# Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1)

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I'm making an AdWords Script (it uses javascript) and gives me this error: `"Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1)"`. I can't find the error. Please help? Thanks

```
function main() {
    var todayDate = getDateString(new Date(),'H');
    Logger.log('Son las '+todayDate+' horas');
    if (todayDate = 11) {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("CPC Log "+getDateString(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yy'));
        var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
        var report = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT CampaignName, AdGroupName, KeywordMaxCpc FROM ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING TODAY");
        report.exportToSheet(sheet);
        var expectedRatio = 30;
        var CpcMultiplier = 1.2;
        CPCmodifier(expectedRatio,sheet,CpcMultiplier);
    }
}
```

I add the complete code, if someone needs to take a look at it:

```
function main() {
    var todayDate = getDateString(new Date(), 'H');
    Logger.log('Son las ' + todayDate + ' horas');
    if (todayDate == 11) {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("CPC Log " + getDateString(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yy'));
        var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
        var report = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT CampaignName, AdGroupName, KeywordMaxCpc FROM ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING TODAY");
        report.exportToSheet(sheet);
        var expectedRatio = 30;
        var CpcMultiplier = 1.2;
        CPCmodifier(expectedRatio, sheet, CpcMultiplier);
    }
}

function getDateString(date, format) {
    return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone(), format);
}

function CPCmodifier(ratio, sheet, CpcMultiplier) {
    var CampaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns().withCondition("Status = PAUSED").get();
    while (CampaignIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaign = CampaignIterator.next();
        var campaignName = campaign.getName();
        var campaignBudget = campaign.getBudget();
        var campaignSpent = campaign.getStatsFor("TODAY").getCost();
        var campaignSpentRatio = (campaignSpent / campaignBudget) * 100;
        Logger.log("La campaña " + campaignName + " lleva gastados $" + campaignSpent + " sobre un presupuesto de $" + campaignBudget + ". Esto representa el " + campaignSpentRatio + "%.");
        if (campaignSpentRatio < ratio) {
            var adGroupIterator = AdWordsApp.adGroups().withCondition("Status = ENABLED").withCondition("CampaignName = '" + campaignName + "'").get();
            while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
                var adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();
                var adGroupName = adGroup.getName();
                for (var row = 2; row > 1; row++) {
                    var cName = sheet.getRange("A" + row).getValue();
                    var agName = sheet.getRange("B" + row).getValue();
                    if (cName == '') break;
                    if (cName == campaignName && agName = adGroupName) {
                        var agMaxCpc = sheet.getRange("C" + row).getValue();
                        if (agMaxCpc == '--') {
                            Logger.log("El grupo de anuncios " + adGroupName + "(campaña " + campaignName + ") no tiene CPC definido. No se aplicarán modificaciones.");
                            break;
                        } else {
                            var agNewCpc = agMaxCpc * CpcMultiplier;
                            Logger.log("El CPC Máximo predeterminado del grupo de anuncios " + adGroupName + "(campaña " + campaignName + ") es de " + agMaxCpc + ". Cambiándolo a " + agNewCpc);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                adGroup.setKeywordMaxCpc(agNewCpc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SOLVED:

I found this:

```
 if (cName == campaignName && agName **=** adGroupName) {
```

and it should be:

```
 if (cName == campaignName && agName == adGroupName) {
```

Comment: `if (todayDate = 11) `: this is assignment; use `==` (or `===`) for comparison.

Comment: Is that the only error you're getting? Is this the complete code?

Comment: Is there another script that you import before this one?

Comment: The reason we ask if there's more code is because that error shouldn't be caused by the code shown.

Comment: Just for grins: see what happens if you put a semicolon before the `function` keyword on the first line of your script.

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

Replace:

```
if (todayDate = 11) {  // That's an assignment
```

With:

```
if (todayDate == 11) { // That's an "equals" operator
```

Comment: I agree that that's a serious problem, but I don't think it would cause the error he/she's getting.

Comment: Hi! I made this replacement but the error doesn't disappear

Comment: @user1475216: Did you post all relevant code? The rest of the code you provided shouldn't be causing issues.

Comment: I now edited my post to put all the code. I thought as the error is in line 1 it shouldn't be affected by the rest.

Comment: I did. The error usually means some kind of syntax mistake, but that doesn't seem to be the case in that code.

Comment: All research I did showed some sort of mistake in concatenation or what you have already fixed.

Comment: thanks! I found the error:  if (cName == campaignName && agName = adGroupName)

Comment: Ah, there we go! That's a similar error :P
Would you consider accepting this answer, please? :3